# Javascript click start / stop interval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to start a interval / function if the user clicks on a button and stop that if the user clicks on stop. But somehow it immidietly starts the startRecord function. What am I doing wrong.

HTML:

```js
window.onload = startRecord;

startRecord = document.getElementById('startRecord');
stopRecord = document.getElementById('stopRecord');

function startRecord() {
  startRecord.onclick = generateImg(true);
  startRecord.style.display = "none";
  stopRecord.style.display = "block";
}

function stopRecord() {
  stopRecord.onclick = generateImg(false);
  startRecord.style.display = "block";
  stopRecord.style.display = "none";
}

function generateImg(start) {
  if (start) {
    var startInterval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("foo")
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log("stop foo")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="startRecord">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Start</a>
        </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="stopRecord">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Stop</a>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to define `startInterval` as a global variable. When you try to stop, `startInterval` would have lost its scope and  in turn its value

Comment: by `window.onload = startRecord;` , startRecord will be called when page is loaded.

Comment: Also, definitely don't give the same name to variables and functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Interval Not Clearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109051/simple-interval-not-clearing)

Comment: @Pengyy how shuold I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues with your code:**

- Your variable name and function name is same:

```js
startRecord = document.getElementById('startRecord');
function startRecord() {
```

as the variables are hoisted, `startRecord` will hold last assigned value.

- Its a bad idea to use `onclick = function`. Every assignment would replace previous value. Use `.addEventListener` instead.
- You are updating UI states on `startRecord` and `endRecord` but on click, these function are not called. Use a function to do all that in one function and use that as event handler.
- `startInterval` is a local variable. So when you click on stop, it has lost its scope. Define it as a global variable.

**Sample Code**

```js
var startInterval = null;

var startRecordBtn = document.getElementById('startRecord');
var stopRecordBtn = document.getElementById('stopRecord');

function registerEvents(){
  startRecordBtn.addEventListener("click", startRecord);
  stopRecordBtn.addEventListener("click", stopRecord);
}

function startRecord() {
  generateImg(true);
  startRecordBtn.style.display = "none";
  stopRecordBtn.style.display = "block";
}

function stopRecord() {
  generateImg(false);
  startRecordBtn.style.display = "block";
  stopRecordBtn.style.display = "none";
}

function generateImg(start) {
  if (start) {
    startInterval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("foo")
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log("stop foo")
  }
}

registerEvents();
window.addEventListener("load", startRecord);
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="startRecord">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Start</a>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="stopRecord">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Stop</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Thanks for the answer, somehow I do not Need this `window.addEventListener("load", startRecord);` it works without it

Comment: I just mentioned good practices and made your code working. Hope it helped you in some way

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define `var startInterval` in global scope.

```
startRecordButton = document.getElementById('startRecord');
stopRecordButton = document.getElementById('stopRecord');
startRecordButton.onclick = startRecord;
stopRecordButton.onclick = stopRecord;

var startInterval;

function startRecord() {
  generateImg(true);
  startRecord.style.display = "none";
  stopRecord.style.display = "block";
}

function stopRecord() {
  generateImg(false);
  startRecord.style.display = "block";
  stopRecord.style.display = "none";
}

function generateImg(start) {
  if (start) {
    startInterval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("foo")
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log("stop foo")
  }
}
```

Comment: @Micheasl sorry, i missunderstood your question. Please check my updated solution now.

Answer (score 1):

remove the onload event, bind event directly to the buttons.
see the node snippet.

```js
btnStartRecord = document.getElementById('startRecord');
btnStopRecord = document.getElementById('stopRecord');

window.onload = function() {
  btnStartRecord.style.display = "block";
  btnStopRecord.style.display = "none";
}

var startInterval;



function startRecord() {
  generateImg(true);
  btnStartRecord.style.display = "none";
  btnStopRecord.style.display = "block";
}

function stopRecord() {
  generateImg(false);
  btnStartRecord.style.display = "block";
  btnStopRecord.style.display = "none";
}

function generateImg(start) {
  if (start) {
    startInterval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("foo")
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
    console.log("stop foo")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" onclick="startRecord()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="startRecord">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Start</a>
        </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="stopRecord()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="stopRecord">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up">Stop</a>
        </button>
</div>
```